# Python Pandas read_csv Keep Column Order

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a CSV file into pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

However, I notice that column order is not preserved. I can't find anything in the docs that explain how to keep the column order when reading in the CSV file.

Comment: Can you post raw input data to support this claim, I've never experienced a situation where the column order is not preserved

Comment: I experienced what I thought was this problem but realised I was comparing against an array initialised with a dict e.g. `pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]})` ... the dict not the DataFrame being the source of the non-determinism

Answer (score 0):

`read.csv` convert tabular data into `DataFrame` object. Since `DataFrame` are `kwargs` dictionary, order is not persevered.

Sources from [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [read.csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-read-csv-table)

Answer (score -2):

you can pass list of the columns with the order you would like them to have:

```
columns = ['a', 'x', 'b', 'y']
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=columns)
```

Comment: one might want to infer the column names from the csv, and retain the ordering in the csv

Comment: [Documentation of`usecols`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) explicitly says that "Element order is ignored, so usecols=[0, 1] is the same as [1, 0]."